# Augmenting theme in material-ui requires explicit casting

Tags: typescript, material-ui

Following the directions in the documentation I've been trying to customize my theme in typescript. Here is what I have

```
import { default as createMuiTheme, ThemeOptions, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme';
import helpers, { Helpers } from './theme.helpers';

declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme' {
  interface Theme {
    helpers: Helpers;
  }
  // allow configuration using `createMuiTheme`
  interface ThemeOptions {
    helpers?: Helpers;
  }
}

function createTheme(options: ThemeOptions) {
  return (createMuiTheme as (options: ThemeOptions) => Theme) ({
    helpers,
   ...options,
  })
}

const theme = createCustomTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#2D3E50',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#1BBC93',
    },
  }
});
```

The problem is two fold:

1. I shouldn't need to explicitly cast `createMuiTheme` but if I don't I get

   > [ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof import("@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme")' has no compatible call signatures.
2. I can't actually use the createTheme function, it reports this error

   > [ts]
   >   Argument of type '{ palette: { primary: { main: string; }; secondary: { main: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ThemeOptions'.
   >   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'palette' does not exist in type 'ThemeOptions'.

Comment: I'm assuming `createCustomTheme` was supposed to be `createTheme`.  When I compile your code, I get no errors even if I remove the cast of `createMuiTheme`.  Make sure your IDE is finding the material-ui typings: try a "jump to definition" on `createMuiTheme` and you should go to `node_modules/@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme.d.ts`.  If that isn't working, try compiling with `--traceResolution` to get more information.

Comment: Did you follow the guide at [material-ui.com › Typescript › Customization of Theme](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#customization-of-theme)?